# What kind of temporal texture filtering is this and how do I disable it?

Tags: opengl, 3d, unreal-engine4

For the project I'm working on I'm updating a texture dynamically in unreal engine with the framebuffer from an emulator. When I manually inspect the texture in the editor everything looks fine. It looks like whats on the right in the image. However the ingame rendered texture is rendered with a weird temporal filter applied to it. Its fairly subtle in the still image, but you can barely see how the text is kind of fading in instead of updating immediately. Its more apparent in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeGpYngg4Bg&feature=youtu.be) I'm guessing its for blending when loading different LoD or something.

I've already disabled mip maps and texture filtering is set to nearest neighbor, so its definitely something else that's causing this.

If you just know what this type of texture filtering is called that would be really helpful for narrowing down my search. If you know how to disable it in Unreal Engine that would be a godsend.

[image: bad texture filtering]

Comment: Probably caused by UE4's Temporal Anti-Aliasing. You can replace it with FXAA, or MSAA if using forward rendering.

Comment: @Rotem Damn that was it. Thanks man you saved me a lot of time. Who knows how long I would have thought it was a texture filtering issue.